Rats and Mice: What do they prefer to eat? (Taste wise)
Rats and mice have different physiology then us humans. They evolved under different conditions.
So what do they prefer taste wise? I'm guessing sugars, as rats and mice have fast metabolisms and sugar is taken up quickly in us mammals.

maybe split this question into two,one for rats and one for mice,it should be possible to find some data about the two most studied types mamals on our planet.

Also: is your question focused on preference or a healthy / balanced diet? Human children also prefer sugar and some would probably love to eat nothing but sweets, but that doesn't mean it would be good for them.

Healthy diet? Lol! We humans shove sugar and fat into EVERYTHING! So why would a society of rats and mice be different? Uh... Sorry, I... Lost the plot a bit there.

Rats and Mice likes high-calorie foods that are rich in fats and carbohydrates. They have a particular fondness for grains, seeds, nuts, and fruits. Most of the time they would eat anything probably but seeds, nuts and stuff is most likely the best choice.
Of course Rats and Mice has different taste buds that has very little difference.
For example, rats tend to have a preference for sweet and fatty foods, which may be related to their higher sensitivity to sweetness compared to mice. On the other hand, mice are more sensitive to bitter tastes, which may help them detect and avoid potentially toxic substances in their environment.
Overall, while mice and rats have similar taste bud structures, their specific preferences and sensitivities to different tastes can vary based on factors such as species, genetics, and individual experiences. So yea, rats likes sweet and fatty foods but mice doesn't like bitter tastes that much. Overall you should give them nuts, fruits and other high-calorie foods that are rich in fats.

This post lacks of any kind of source. Please give information where your hypothesis comes from.
